# FluentAssertions Should.Equal on collections, containing nulls

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

FluentAssertions seems to fail with NullReferece exception when I try comparing two collections with nulls

```
    [Test]
    public void DeepWithNulls()
    {
        var l1 = new List<string> { "aaa", null };
        var l2 = new List<string> { "aaa", null };

        l1.Should().Equal(l2);
    }
```

Comparison works as expected on collections with no nulls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening due to the fact that deep down in the collection comparison logic Fluent Assertion uses following code

```
 for (int index = 0; index < expectedItems.Length; index++)
            {
                verification.ForCondition((index < actualItems.Length) && actualItems[index].Equals(expectedItems[index]))
                    .FailWith("Expected " + Verification.SubjectNameOr("collection") +
                        " to be equal to {0}{reason}, but {1} differs at index {2}.", expected, Subject, index);
            }
```

in above code `expectedItems` and `actualItems` are your lists

Now think what will happen during second iteration when (part below) will be executed?

`actualItems[index].Equals(expectedItems[index])`

as `actualItems[1]` is `null` so it throws null reference exception

Comment: Is there some workaround with Fluent Assertions? Or I have to use cycles in unit tests if I`m sure that nulls are normal for tested collections?

Comment: for now I would suggest make sure there is no null in collection before calling equal and file a bug on `codeplex` site of `fluentassertion`. Another option could be to download the source and fix it yourself :)

Comment: @tensorsigma - I would advise against downloading the source and changing it.  Once you start adding in custom fixes you'll be reluctant to download updates to the project, since you'll have to re-add all that stuff.  Unless of course the project owners accept your changes and incorporate them into the project code base.

Comment: Fixed in both the 1.7.0 release branch as well as in the trunk. If you want, you can compile an updated version directly from the source code: – Dennis Doomen